# Don't have the horizontal scrolling in mobile devices

Tags: html, css

So, I want to make a horizontal scrolling and disable the vertical scrolling. How should I do it?

P.S. Also I have a problem with the site's view when changing the browser's size.

Please, advice me and tell me what should I do.

(Don't have more details)

Can't scroll horizontally:

[image]

And this happens while using the vertical scrolling:

[image]

[This is Site](http://ksrf.tk/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.Header {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: top;
    width:100%; 
    height:13.5%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.News {
    color: #6a70b3;
    font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, "sans-serif";
    font-size: 11.3333px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 40%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

section { /*Контент*/
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12.8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    width:900px; 
    height:300px; 
    position:fixed; 
    left:20%; 
    top:110px;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

section a:visited {
    color:#003399;
}

section a:hover {
    color: black;
}

aside { /*Sidebar*/
    padding: 5% 0.5%;
    margin: 0% auto;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width:15%; 
    background-image: url(../images/side.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-size: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 10%;
    z-index: 1;
}

aside li { /*Sidebar Список */
    font-family: Verdana, Arial , "sans-serif", helvetica;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    width: 70%;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    
}
/* Стиль верхней панели навигации */
.topnav {
    margin:6.2%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5%;
    top: 0%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 2;
    
}

/* Стиль ссылок навигации */
.topnav a {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    line-height: 7px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    float:left;
    font-family: verdana, "sans-serif", helvetica, arial;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 3;
}

/* Изменение цвета при наведении */
.topnav a:hover {
    color: orange;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none; /* Убираем маркеры */
    text-decoration: none; /* Убираем подчёркивание */
    margin-left: 0; /* Отступ слева в браузере IE и Opera */
    padding-left: 0; /* Отступ слева в браузере Firefox, Safari, Chrome */
}

ul a{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: darkblue;
}

ul a:hover{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:orange;
}

#mainText {
    text-align: center;
}

.border {
    color:black;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

footer { /*Подвал*/
    text-align: center;
    margin-right:0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 50px;
    float: none;
    position: fixed;
}

footer a{ 
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10.6667px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 17%;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#06C;
    height: 50px;
    float: none;
}

.footerline {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 1px;
    left: 0px;
    float: none;
}


@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) { /*iPad*/
    body {
        overflow: scroll;
    }
    aside {
        min-width: 17%;
        min-height: 100%;
        top: 5%;
    }
    
    .topnav {
        top: 0.5%;
    }
}


@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) {
/*iPhone SE*/
    body {
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
        aside {
        min-width: 55%;
        min-height: 100%;
        top: 8%;
    }
    
    header {
        
    }
    .topnav {
        top: 5.4%;
        left: 40%;
        height: 3.5%;
    }
    
    section {
        top: 14%;
        left: 61%;
    }
    
    footer a{
        left: 80%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1650px) { /*fullHD*/
    aside {
        width: 10%;
        min-height: 100%;
        top: 8%;
    }
    
    .topnav {
        top: -2.3%;
        height: 2%;
    }
    
    .News {
    color: #6a70b3;
    font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, "sans-serif";
    font-size: 12.3333px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 50%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-left: 14%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>    
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
<title>Новости - Анонсы</title>
    </head>
<body>
     <header>
    <img src="images/headerfinal.png" class="Header" alt="Header">
    </header>
    <nav>
    <div class="topnav"> <!--Верхнее меню -->
  <a href="news.html">Новости</a>
  <a href="#top">О Суде</a>
  <a href="#top">Решения КС РФ</a>
  <a href="#top">Заседания КС РФ</a>
  <a href="#top">Контакты</a>
    </div>
    </nav>
    
    <section> <!-- Основной текст -->
<div class="News"><h3>Новости - Анонсы</h3></div>
<br>
<p>10 ноября 2017 года Конституционный Суд РФ провозгласит Постановление по делу о проверке конституционности Федерального закона «О внесении изменений в отдельные законодательные акты РФ в части совершенствования законодательства о публичных мероприятиях»</p>
<br>
<p>( <a href="#top">подробнее...</a>)</p>
<br>
<p>7 ноября 2017 года Конституционный Суд РФ провозгласил Постановление по делу о проверке конституционности ряда положений Закона Республики Крым «Об особенностях регулирования имущественных и земельных отношений на территории Республики Крым»</p>
<br>
<p>( <a href="#top">подробнее...</a>)</p>

<br>
    <a href="#top">Посмотреть все новости</a>
<br>
    </section>
    <aside> <!-- Меню слева -->
<ul>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<li><a href="news.html">Новости</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">О Суде</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">Решения КС РФ</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">Заседания КС РФ</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<img src="images/gerb.gif" alt="Герб РФ" align=center>
    </aside>
<br>
<br>
    <footer>
        <hr style="border:1px; height:1px; width: 70%; margin-left: 270px; background-color:black">
    <img src="images/footer.PNG" class=footerline alt="Footer">
        <a href="index.html">©Конституционный Суд Российской Федерации, 2008-2017</a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you really messed up with HTML code and css. Layout structure should be clear in your mind for any website you work. I'll suggest you to learn bootstrap this will help you a lot.

```css
nav{float: left;width: 75%;}
.News {
    color: #6a70b3;
    font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, "sans-serif";
    font-size: 11.3333px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 40%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

section { /*Контент*/
        font-family: Arial;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12.8px;
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}

section a:visited {
    color:#003399;
}

section a:hover {
    color: black;
}

aside { /*Sidebar*/
    padding: 5% 0.5%;
    margin: 0% auto;
    width: 20%;
    background-image: url(../images/side.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: auto;
    float: left;
}

aside li { /*Sidebar Список */
    font-family: Verdana, Arial , "sans-serif", helvetica;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    width: 70%;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    
}
/* Стиль верхней панели навигации */
.topnav {
        margin: 6.2% 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    
}

/* Стиль ссылок навигации */
.topnav a {
        margin-left: 3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    line-height: 7px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: verdana, "sans-serif", helvetica, arial;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Изменение цвета при наведении */
.topnav a:hover {
    color: orange;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none; /* Убираем маркеры */
    text-decoration: none; /* Убираем подчёркивание */
    margin-left: 0; /* Отступ слева в браузере IE и Opera */
    padding-left: 0; /* Отступ слева в браузере Firefox, Safari, Chrome */
}

ul a{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: darkblue;
}

ul a:hover{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:orange;
}

#mainText {
    text-align: center;
}

.border {
    color:black;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

footer { /*Подвал*/
        width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}



.footerline {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 1px;
    left: 0px;
    float: none;
}



    .News {
    color: #6a70b3;
    font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, "sans-serif";
    font-size: 12.3333px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 50%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-left: 14%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>    
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
<title>Новости - Анонсы</title>
    </head>
<body>
     <header>
    <img src="images/headerfinal.png" class="Header" alt="Header">
    </header>
 
 <aside> <!-- Меню слева -->
<ul>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<li><a href="news.html">Новости</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">О Суде</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">Решения КС РФ</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">Заседания КС РФ</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<img src="images/gerb.gif" alt="Герб РФ" align=center>
    </aside>  
    <nav>
    <div class="topnav"> <!--Верхнее меню -->
  <a href="news.html">Новости</a>
  <a href="#top">О Суде</a>
  <a href="#top">Решения КС РФ</a>
  <a href="#top">Заседания КС РФ</a>
  <a href="#top">Контакты</a>
    </div>
    </nav>
 
    <section> <!-- Основной текст -->
<div class="News"><h3>Новости - Анонсы</h3></div>
<br>
<p>10 ноября 2017 года Конституционный Суд РФ провозгласит Постановление по делу о проверке конституционности Федерального закона «О внесении изменений в отдельные законодательные акты РФ в части совершенствования законодательства о публичных мероприятиях»</p>
<br>
<p>( <a href="#top">подробнее...</a>)</p>
<br>
<p>7 ноября 2017 года Конституционный Суд РФ провозгласил Постановление по делу о проверке конституционности ряда положений Закона Республики Крым «Об особенностях регулирования имущественных и земельных отношений на территории Республики Крым»</p>
<br>
<p>( <a href="#top">подробнее...</a>)</p>

<br>
    <a href="#top">Посмотреть все новости</a>
<br>
    </section>

<br>
<br>
    <footer>
        <hr style="border:1px;width:60%; height:1px;background-color:black">
    <img src="images/footer.PNG" class=footerline alt="Footer">
        <a href="index.html">©Конституционный Суд Российской Федерации, 2008-2017</a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

you can use this code hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

But i have a one little problem now, sidebar is not on full height and topnav in the middle of page. [link](http://ksrf.tk/)

Comment: I've updated code in the previous answer please check. Goodluck